# Tkinter String concatenation

Tags: python, tkinter, project

So I am trying to make an app where the user inputs his/her username and stores it into a text file where the username and password is separated by ";"

```
UserName=create_entry_1.get()
Password=create_entry_2.get()
```

then I try to do

```
Text_string=UserName+";"+ Password
```

but I'm having an error which says:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'StringVar' and 'str'"
```

Could someone please help me solve this error??

Comment: Try `Text_string = UserName.get() + ";" +  Password.get()`

Comment: What kind of widgets are `UserName` and `Password`? If they are the same type of widgets then `.get()` should return values of the same type -- either both `str` or both `StringVar` -- but the error message says otherwise. Please clarify.

Comment: If you get that error, `UserName`  and/or `Password` must be a `StringVar`, but you're assuming it's a string. Please show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:-

```
Text_string = str(Username) + ";" + str(Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the .get() function returns a string from an entry form.
I re-checked and re-installed the tkinter library and works fine!
Idk why the library didn't work in the first place but all's well that ends well!